# How do I persist CLLocation between app launches?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to persist 2 CLLocations between app launches. This is the ONLY data I want stored in memory between launches. How do I go about doing this? Does CLLocation have a writetofile or store it in coredata or NSUserDefaults? I want to store the whole CLLocation object, don't want to store only lat/lon and then do more calculations etc. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the documentation I see that `CLLocation` implements the `NSCoding` protocol.

This means that you can *archive* and *unarchive* a `CLLocation` instance by using the `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` classes.

You can also put multiple instances of `CLLocation` in any container (parent) class that implements `NSCoder` like for example `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` and then archive or unarchive that whole collection of objects.

See the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html) for more detailed info. Or post a followup question with code if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

St3fan's answer is what I went worth and is working great. Simple solution to a simple problem! I thought I'd share the code I came up with.

I have a Singleton class that holds my `CLLocationManager`, this class handles the persistence and forwards the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` methods to an array of delegates in case multiple classes are interested in these messages (and that's always been the case with my apps).

This code probably won't work as a copy/paste job, but if you can't figure out what you need from this, look up the singleton pattern and learn it! `_lastLocation` is an ivar with a readonly property for other classes to read. `persistLastLocation` does the work of saving the location. You should call it whenever you get a new location.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.myLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.myLocationManager.delegate = self;

        // Some config
        self.myLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = 482; // .3 miles
        self.myLocationManager.distanceFilter = 200;


        NSLog(@"CLLocationManager authStatus on start up: %d", [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]);
        NSLog(@"Location services enabled: %d", [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]);

        CLLocation *decodedLocation = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self lastLocationPersistenceFilePath]];
        if (decodedLocation) {
            NSLog(@"Decoded location: %@", decodedLocation);
            _lastLocation = decodedLocation;
        }

    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark MyLocationManager
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (NSString *)lastLocationPersistenceFilePath {
    NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"my_app_last_location"];
    return filePath;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)persistLastLocation {   
    BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.lastLocation
                                               toFile:[self lastLocationPersistenceFilePath]];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Could not persist location for some reason!");
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    // Forward this message to the new iOS 6 delegate method.
    [self locationManager:manager didUpdateLocations:@[oldLocation]];
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *latestLocation = [locations lastObject];

    _lastLocation = latestLocation;
    [self persistLastLocation];    
}
```